# Is there a way in android to set a field via xml android:id into a custom view

Tags: java, android, xml, dependency-injection

For instance I have a custom button and want to connect it to a SeekBar:

```
public class SeekBarButton extends ImageButton {

    SeekBar seekBar;

    public SeekBarButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SeekBarButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SeekBarButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void setSeekBar(SeekBar seekBar) {
        this.seekBar = seekBar;
    }

    public SeekBar getSeekBar() {
        return seekBar;
    }
}
```

I can do it in the code:

```
sbb = (SeekBarButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.minus_red);
sbRed = (SeekBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sbRed);
sbb.setSeekBar(sbRed);
```

But 8 buttons will give a lot of boilerplate, and I want something like:

```
    <com.whatever.views.SeekBarButton
        ...
        whatToPutHere:seekbar="@+id/sbRed"  // like this? whatToPutHere?
        android:id="@+id/minus_red" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbRed"

        ... />
```

Comment: you can set tag progratically.

Comment: But I'm looking for via XML

Comment: progratically editing xml is not possible

Comment: you can create your custom attribute for your custom component like this example [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/create_custom_attributes_for_custom_component.htm)

Comment: Yes John, and If custom attribute has "id" android:id="@+id/sbRed, and I need this instance?

Comment: I just realized my answer may not be as helpful as I thought. You are probably asking about how to get the XML to pull the (int) value associated with `"@id/sbRed"` and assign it to `blah:seekbar=` Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a way to inject the SeekBar into the SeekBarButton (via id or whatever): red sb - into the red button, green sb - into the green button ... and avoid a lot of boilerplate java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a custom `ViewGroup` that contains both the `Button` and `Seekbar`. **If you cannot do that**, for any reason, here's a solution:

There are a few steps to make this work. First you must define a custom XML attribute that you can then reference and use.

Edit (or create) `res/values/attrs.xml`. Add:

```
<declare-styleable name="SeekBarButton">
    <attr name="seekbarId" format="integer" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Then, in `SeekBarButton`, call this from the constructors:

```
private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    if (attrs != null) {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.SeekBarButton, defStyleAttr, 0);
        mSeekbarId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.SeekBarButton_seekbarId, 0);
        a.recycle();
    }
}
```

Finally, in your root `ViewGroup` of your layout file, add

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Then,

```
<com.whatever.views.SeekBarButton
    android:id="@+id/minus_red"
    app:seekbarId="@+id/sbRed"
    ... />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sbRed"
    ... />
```

**Note** You will need to call `((ViewGroup) getParent()).findViewById(mSeekbarId)` in `SeekBarButton` to instantiate the `SeekBar`, but `getParent()` will be null in `SeekBarButton` constructors. So, delay `findViewById()` until you need the `SeekBar`.

Comment: First off: I'm admittedly fairly new to this. Is there a reason you suggested `app:seekbarId` instead of `custom:seekbarId`? I thought "custom" was required but if there's another way to achieve the same goal, I'm glad to know when it's appropriate to use each of the two options. Thanks.

Comment: @Chamatake-san You can use whatever namespace you want. All that matters is that it's the same one that you set in your root layout. E.g.  `xmlns:app` = `app:seekbarId`, `xmlns:custom` = `custom:seekbarId`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are close. In the first XML tag of your layout file (my example is a `RelativeLayout`) you need this reference to "custom":

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

Then farther down wherever your custom ImageButton is, you need this:

```
<com.whatever.views.SeekBarButton
        ...
        custom:seekbar="@+id/sbRed"
        android:id="@+id/minus_red" />
```

You will also need a `seekBarButton.xml` file in your `project\res\values` folder, if you didn't already know that.